# c++ sprintf remove undefined behavior

Tags: c++, printf, valgrind

I know, that something like this

```
char a[1024] = "Hello";
char b[6] = "World";

sprintf(a, "%s %s", a, b);
```

causes undefined behavior. I know, I could use other functions like `strcat` but if I want to use the `sprintf` function (I know the risk I could write over the array boundaries) could I remove the undefined behavior if I write something like this

```
sprintf(a + strlen(a), "%s %s", a, b)
```

or is it still undefined and I have to use a temporary variable?

Comment: Why are you using crufty C library functions instead of modern C++ streams-based code? They have their uses, in carefully controlled scenarios, but this is not one of them. Are you writing C or C++ code? If these were `std::string`s, then you'd just write `a = a + " " + b;` and be done with it.

Comment: What makes you think the second example might be UB? You'd need a space on the front of your format string to match the first example

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Both. C and C++.

Comment: I agree with @Sam, but if you are going to use "crufty" C functions, you can make them a bit less crufty by using their return values, which are returned for a purpose. If you are building a string in pieces, you should always know where the current end of the string is (and you need to know that to avoid buffer overflow). Since `sprintf` helpfully returns the number of characters it wrote, you just need to add that to the current end of the string to get the new end. Also, use `snprintf` and tell it how much space you have left. Don't just say "This isn't serious code so I can cut corners."

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sorry, I wrote the wrong example. I meant something like Andreas Wenzel wrote.

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer: If your question contains an error, then you might want to edit it (so that it makes more sense). That way, your question is more likely to get upvoted. For example, I did not upvote your question (nobody did) because it did not make much sense to me and I had to guess what you meant when writing my answer.

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer: Since you stated in your comment that you gave the wrong example in your question and that you meant what I wrote in my answer, I have now submitted an edit proposal, so that your question makes more sense. If I misunderstood you and this is not what you want, then please feel free to reject my edit proposal. If you accept my edit proposal, please notify me and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer: By the way, I do not see any significance in having the `for` loop. You may want to remove that loop as well or at least explain the significance of the loop in your question.

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer: Since my edit proposal was accepted (not by you, but by two other people), I have now edited my answer accordingly, by removing the part which referenced your previous example. However, feel free to revert my edit to your question if it was not what you intended.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you. I was at work and had no time so far.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Without the for loop valgrind did not give any kind of warning because of the overlapping objects. I will remove it.

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer: Ok, now the question is more clean and focused, so I have upvoted it. However, I'm afraid that it won't be upvoted by many other people, because it is a specific problem that is not of much general interest. I may be wrong, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the line

`sprintf(a, "%s %s", a, b);`

will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because the source and destination strings overlap.

However, the line

`sprintf(a + strlen(a), "%s %s", a, b);`

would still cause undefined behavior, because `a + strlen(a)` is the address of the terminating null character of the string `a` (which means the source string `a` and the destination string `a + strlen(a)` still overlap). If the strings should not overlap, then the line must be changed to the following:

`sprintf(a + strlen(a) + 1, "%s %s", a, b);`

Since there is no longer any overlap, the line will not cause undefined behavior.

If you want to be able to copy memory from one memory buffer to another memory buffer which overlaps the first memory buffer, then I recommend using the function [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove). In contrast to [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy), the function `memmove` permits overlapping memory buffers and behaves as if the content were first written to a temporary buffer before being written to the destination buffer. Therefore, the behavior of that function is not undefined, but well-defined, even if the buffers overlap. Unfortunately, there is no equivalent function `strmove` for strings.

Comment: Why doesn't cause your last example undefined behavior? The content doesn't overlap (you write after the Null byte), but the variable memory space (variable a) does overlap. I see that you "append" b after the Null byte so if I print the variable a after the sprintf call I wouldn't see the appended content.

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer: Yes, you are right that you wouldn't see the appended content if you print `a` after the call to `sprintf`. However, the behavior is still well-defined (not undefined). Technically, there is nothing wrong with storing several strings inside the memory buffer `a` (as long as all strings are properly terminated with a null character). Whether it is meaningful or not is of course a different issue. The behavior is only undefined if the source string and the destination string in the `sprintf` function call overlap.

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer: Or you have to use `memmove` if they do overlap. That function behaves as if the content were first written to a temporary buffer before being written to the destination buffer. Therefore, the behavior of that function is not undefined, but well-defined, even if the buffers overlap. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> could I remove the undefined behavior if I write something like this
>
> ```
> sprintf(a + strlen(a), "%s", b)
> ```
>
> or is it still undefined and I have to use a temporary variable?

Yes, you could. No it wouldn't still be UB.

---

Edit:

> could I remove the undefined behavior if I write something like this
>
> ```
> sprintf(a + strlen(a), "%s %s", a, b)
> ```
>
> or is it still undefined and I have to use a temporary variable?

No, you couldn't. It would still be UB because you still write to the string that you pass as an argument.